# Is this UTF-8 encoding correct?

Tags: qt, utf-8

I have a Qt application (C++) and I have a unicode string (in QString).
I send the string to 2 clients, one receiving binary data, and another JSON.

When I send the following string "Milanović" the letter "ć" gets screwed up on client-side. Though I am not even sure if it's sent correctly from the server.

I am sending the following bytes for that character to the client that accepts binary data: c4 86. That's what I am getting from QString::toUtf8().

For JSON i am using QJson, which converts that string to "MilanoviÄ". Well, that's what i see in the console. The bytes are still "c4 86".

Is that correct, or should I maybe change something on the server side? I could change the QJson lib to not do the conversion for characters with code > 127, but I'd rather not, unless I must. Please advise.

Comment: The bytes are still `c4 86`, so it didn't change anything. The bytes are just interpreted in wrong encoding. You need to inform whatever screen that is showing the characters that what encoding those bytes are in.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the clients tell the server what encoding they actually want and then run the text through an appropriate QTextEncoder before sending it to the client.